# Prerequisites for advanced calculus

Tags: reference-request, soft-question

What are the prerequisites for advanced calculus? , I've studied till chapter 3 from Spivak's calculus on manifolds, although I understand it Im not really good with exercises, I haven't studied real analysis officially but I've studied calculus, so I'm asking if taking advanced calculus to be the next step is a good idea.

Books Recommendations will be appreciated.

Comment: If you're studying from Spivak's Calculus on manifolds, that's already a good step. Although Spivak's text may be abstract, I think it's a very nice book. Personally, I found it very helpful to supplement it with Loomis and Sternberg's advanced calculus (this is available freely online; overall, they treat things more generally than Spivak, but in some places, I found the generality and exposition to be clearer). Also, Duistermaat and Kolk's analysis texts (both differentiation and integration) are very nice, they're on the level of Spivak, though more elaborate, and MANY problems.

Comment: however I think the issue now isn't to read from several textbooks. You should instead focus on trying to solve many problems. For this, I really like the book by Duistermaat. It has many nice guided problems (very much like Spivak's regular calculus text), and if you've studied up to chapter 3 in Spivak's calculus on manifolds, you should be able to do a good chunk of the problems here (from both the differentiation and integration part). Also, Hubbard and Hubbard's book on vector calculus, linear algebra, differential forms is very nice. It introduces things more patiently than spivak.

Comment: *(comment from U.S. perspective)* You should indicate what "advanced calculus" means where you're at. The vast majority of the dozens of textbooks titled "advanced calculus" that are used for courses with this name (or at least used to be; this once-standard U.S. 3rd year course started being phased out in the 1980s, even 1970s in some universities) requires only the standard elementary calculus sequence (usually 3 semesters) as a prerequisite. In particular, no linear algebra, no differential equations (except what's in basic calculus texts), and nothing remotely approaching Spivak's book.

Comment: Duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3993579.