# What books should I read before books of Advanced Calculus?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus, self-learning, book-recommendation

I need books to get the right understanding of calculus to read books like Spivak, Apostol and Courant Calculus, I'm a complete beginner at it, since I've had heard those are good books, and I've look at them and they are really interesting books which I'd I'd love to study, but as I've said I don't know much (almost any) about calculus.

I want to know if there are some good references to study before that can help me to don't get stuck (easily) when I am studying or should I go directly to those books, if that is ghe case which one should I read first: **Courant, Apostol or Spivak**

Comment: Calculus by Spivak is designed so that it can serve as an introduction to calculus. So you could try reading it directly. But note that understanding calculus intuitively is a lot easier than developing it rigorously, as Spivak does. For example, the intermediate value theorem is intuitively very believable, but the rigorous proof is a lot of work, especially if you're learning to do proofs for the first time.

Comment: In my opinion, it is good to know a bit about trigonometry (soh-cah-toa), logarithms, e, and natural logs.

Answer (score 0):

I love love loved my calculus book from when I took AP in high school.  It was the two volumes by Best and Penner.  The red and the green.  Highly recommend them.

Answer (score 0):

Calculus by Michael Spivak is one of the most celebrated books in calculus & mathematical analysis.it is the best choice for self study for a beginner. It starts from basic definition and slowly slowly devlopes given all prerequisite it keeps you engaged.Would definitely recommend it. Go for it

Answer (score 0):

Well, to fully understand the concepts of advanced calculus, you should first understand the formal language, so logic, set theory, induction. Then you could start with some basic book on calculus, I have Spivak calculus 4th edition, which I have used a few years ago in University, it's a really nice book, it has a lot of exercises, explain the theory, it has a lot of images, and provides intuition on was going on, so I recommend you this one. Then you can go one step further with numerical series, series of functions, integration (Riemann, Darboux, Stieltjes) and you will be prepared for advanced calculus, Apostol make integrals before derivatives, which is not the usual way to learn, but it's fine. I used Buck's book advanced calculus to learn this course.